# php artisan throws an error: Failed opening required

Tags: php, linux, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

On the linux(Pop_OS) when I created a new laravel project, I tried to run php artisan and I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/dusan/freeCodeGram/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dusan/freeCodeGram/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/dusan/freeCodeGram/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/dusan/freeCodeGram/artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/dusan/freeCodeGram/artisan on line 18
```

I am new to php and laravel and only just starting to learn it, and also note I have installed laravel using composer.

Comment: did you try to change permissions on the root folder ? like `chmod -R 755 /home/dusan/` and run `composer install` and after that to run php artisan commands

Comment: @RobertMihaiIonas greetings no I haven't tried that, I will try it now. Thank you!

Comment: @RobertMihaiIonas I still got the same error,  I went into  `/usr/share/` and there is no php directory at all is that an issue?

Comment: Is this a repo that has not been updated in over 3 years and not a new laravel project? https://github.com/coderstape/freeCodeGram if so, if you are new try to stick to projects that are maintained.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... how did you create the new laravel project?

Comment: @MichaelMano no I just started watching that crash course I haven't pulled anything from the github

Comment: @lagbox so first thing I did is installed composer and then I installed laravel using composer and then I used `laravel new` command to make a new project, and after that i just entered the directory and tried to run `php artisan` command and it threw me this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this command in your project

```
composer update --ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo
```

i hope it was useful !

Comment: ` You can also run 'php --ini' in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-dom` to temporarily ignore these required extensions. `

Comment: I ran `php --ini` but it shows that all of then are enabled.